# Python subprocess module giving an OSError while running UNIX commands

Tags: python-2.7, maven, unix, subprocess

Here's the context: 
I am using python 2.7.5. And I would like to run UNIX commands as well as maven commands in a python script.
I was successful to do so, using `os.system("cmd")`, but I need to work on the result of the given command. After reading the doc and some threads in here, I decided to use the subprocess module to redirect the output to the stdout using PIPE. Unexpectedly, I am getting an OSError as shown in the attached image. Your help will be much appreciated.
In addition to the given sample in the attached image, I have tried:

```
p = os.popen("java -version")
result = subprocess.check_output(p, shell=True)
subprocess.call("ls /usr", shell=True)
p.s. Using shell=True is strongly discouraged (doc), since it can be dangerous when coupled with unsanitized input.
```

Also, I took a look at the given script in the error message `/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py, line 711 adn 1327` but didn't learn more than what is mentionned in the error message: raise child_exception
[Subprocess Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRJtm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using `subprocess.check_output` correctly. You're trying to pass a pipe file object (the return value of `os.popen`) to `check_output` but it's expecting a command argument or argument vector.

Also, the `subprocess.call` function won't capture the executed command's output, so you would only use that if you want the output of `ls /usr` (or whatever) to be seen by the user running the script interactively. (Which is pretty much the same as `os.system`.)

Try this instead (showing with and without the shell):

```
import subprocess

out1a = subprocess.check_output(['java', '-version'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(out1a)

out1b = subprocess.check_output('java -version', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
print(out1b)

out2a = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '/usr'])
print(out2a)

out2b = subprocess.check_output('ls /usr', shell=True)
print(out2b)

# Cannot capture output this way, but it will be visible to user
subprocess.call('ls /usr', shell=True)
```

Note that in the case of the `java -version` command, the version info gets printed to the command's standard error output so you must redirect that in order to capture it as the returned value of `check_output` (hence the `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`).

Comment: Thanks, Gil. the command out1a and its printing is working now. But how could I fextract first line, since I want to check if the version match a certain number? I have tried to redirect the output to a file.txt but not working. Is there a command that helps to extract and work directly with the terminal output?

Comment: The result you get back is a string containing multiple lines of text. Use `out1a.splitlines()` to decompose that into individual lines. That returns a `tuple` from which you can select components you care about. Try, for example, `print(out1a.splitlines()[0])`. Then use other string methods to isolate the version number you need (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?string-methods#string-methods)

Comment: Alright, that helped me solve my problem. Again, thanks Gil. Here's how I completed: `import subprocess
import re

res = subprocess.check_output(['java', '-version'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
res2 = res.splitlines()[0].split()[2]

versionNumber = re.findall('[0-9._]+', res2)
print(versionNumber)

if versionNumber[0] >= 1.7:
 print "Cool"
else:
 print "Install a newer version"`